# COUNT filtering in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by

Assume the following table:
bed small total
bed medium total
bed big total

If there are 100 beds, 10 of them are small, 20 of them are medium and the rest are big. In the third column, I am supposed to get these values, however, my code returns 100 for each row. This is my code:

```
SELECT bed, size, COUNT(bed) AS total
from table
GROUP BY bed, size
ORDER BY bed, size desc
```

Comment: Your query looks ok.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (no images.) Simplify, 10 beds total. [mcve]